# Flask does not redirect to the canonical URL with the trailing slash on GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, flask

I have a simple Flask application.
**On local host, Flask redirects to the canonical URL with the trailing slash**. So if I visit `localhost:8080/test`, it will take me to `localhost:8080/test/`

**However, when I deploy to google app engine**, 
I try `***.appspot.com/test` , it just return 404 error.
It does not redirect to the canonical URL with the trailing slash.
I really can not figure out the problem. I use gae-init https://github.com/gae-init/gae-init

Here is my app.yaml file

```
service: default
instance_class: F1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

builtins:
- appstats: on
- deferred: on
- remote_api: on

inbound_services:
- warmup

libraries:
- name: ssl
  version: latest

error_handlers:
- file: templates/error_static.html

handlers:
- url: /favicon.ico
  static_files: static/img/favicon.ico
  upload: static/img/favicon.ico

- url: /robots.txt
  static_files: static/robots.txt
  upload: static/robots.txt

- url: /p/(.*\.ttf)
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.ttf)
  mime_type: font/ttf
  expiration: "365d"

- url: /p/(.*\.woff2)
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.woff2)
  mime_type: font/woff2
  expiration: "365d"

- url: /p/
  static_dir: static/
  expiration: "365d"

- url: /.*
  script: main.app
  secure: always
  redirect_http_response_code: 301

skip_files:
- ^(.*/)?#.*#
- ^(.*/)?.*/RCS/.*
- ^(.*/)?.*\.bak$
- ^(.*/)?.*\.py[co]
- ^(.*/)?.*~
- ^(.*/)?Icon\r
- ^(.*/)?\..*
- ^(.*/)?app\.yaml
- ^(.*/)?app\.yml
- ^(.*/)?index\.yaml
- ^(.*/)?index\.yml
- ^lib/.*
- ^static/dev/.*
- ^static/ext/.*\.coffee
- ^static/ext/.*\.css
- ^static/ext/.*\.js
- ^static/ext/.*\.less
- ^static/ext/.*\.json
- ^static/src/.*
```

Here is how I handle test

```
@app.route('/test/')
@auth.login_required
def contact_list():
  contact_dbs, contact_cursor = model.Contact.get_dbs(
      user_key=auth.current_user_key(),
    )

  return flask.render_template(
      'contact_list.html',
      html_class='contact-list',
      title='Contact List',
      contact_dbs=contact_dbs,
      next_url=util.generate_next_url(contact_cursor),
    )


The console log is 
2018-06-14 02:45:09.388 JST
301 - Moved Permanently: https://ktest321986.appspot.com/contact (/base/data/home/apps/b~ktest321986/20180613t165904.410404733871213095/control/error.py:29)
2018-06-14 02:45:09.389 JST
301 Moved Permanently: None (/base/data/home/apps/b~ktest321986/20180613t165904.410404733871213095/control/error.py:31)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lib.zip/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "lib.zip/flask/app.py", line 1791, in dispatch_request
    self.raise_routing_exception(req)
  File "lib.zip/flask/app.py", line 1774, in raise_routing_exception
    raise request.routing_exception
RequestRedirect: 301 Moved Permanently: None
```

You can try it here : 
does not work: https://ktest321986.appspot.com/contact
work: https://ktest321986.appspot.com/contact/

Comment: Sounds like browser caching issue.  Do you have `strict_slashes` set anywhere?  `app = Flask(__name__) ... app.url_map.strict_slashes = False`

Comment: i tried on different browser, but same result. I do not have strict_slashes = False anywhere.

Comment: i try gae-init tutorial, u can reproduce the error if you have time by following the tutorial at http://docs.gae-init.appspot.com/tutorial/

Comment: [This](http://docs.gae-init.appspot.com/tutorial/) is a tutorial from another project in GAE and is not an official documentation from the Google App Engine team. I do not rule out the viability of its implementation described, though. However, the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#handlers_element) describes using handlers to manage URL and static files. Hence, I believe the 404 is returned because you are attempting to use a handler, 'test' which does not exist in your App.yaml file.

Comment: i build a /test page which run on local server, it does return a page.

Comment: What's your app.yaml file?

Comment: @blueCat I added app.yaml file. Please note that it works on local, but not on GAE cloud.

Comment: Your App.yaml does not seem to have the handler that manages ***.appspot.com/test. I expect to see a handler URL that handles /test

Comment: I added test handler code. Please note that there is no problem on localhost. problem comes when I deploy to gae cloud :(

Comment: When running locally do you use `dev_appserver.py` or start directly the Flask app?

Comment: And what do you have in Stackdriver logging?

Comment: i added logging error. By the way, I also add the site url. You can try it. Instead of test url, i make it contact url .

Comment: I understand you have a code that handles the test URL, but I still think you should attempt to add the test handlers directly on your App.yaml. Google App Engine uses the App.yaml specifically to manage URL and static files. I recommend that you add the handlers and test to verify if the issue persists

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what is the problem.
However, when I deploy the project from Mac, problem has gone.
If I deploy the project from window 10, problem comes. 
So funny!